# How to remove number in paginate_links function using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i m using paginate_links function in WordPress so default paging like this « Prev 1 … 3 4 5 6 7 … 9 Next » but i want to remove number so it will look like « Prev Next » can it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function paginate_links it is actually said *paginate*, so you don't want this function, you want the next/prev.

Here they explain how to use it : http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links